# How do I draw Graphics in Virtual Pascal?

Tags: graphics, pascal

I've been using VP (Virtual Pascal) to create a school shop as my project. I'm just about done with the program and I'd really like to be able add in graphics. Nothing too fancy, just having a button to click on to go to "Orders" instead of having:

```
Procedure ordersMenu;

  VAR

     orderMenuChoice : CHAR;

  BEGIN
     REPEAT
        CLRSCR;
        TEXTCOLOR(15);
        GOTOXY(30,2);
        WRITELN('Orders Menu');
        TEXTCOLOR(11);
        GOTOXY(30,3);
        WRITELN('-----------');
        WRITELN('');

        WRITE('A ':25);
        TEXTCOLOR(15);
        WRITELN(': Create a New Customer Order');
        WRITELN;
        TEXTCOLOR(11);

        WRITE('B ':25);
        TEXTCOLOR(15);
        WRITELN(': Search For A Customer Order');
        WRITELN;
        TEXTCOLOR(11);

        WRITE('C ':25);
        TEXTCOLOR(15);
        WRITELN(': Delete A Customer Order');
        WRITELN;
        TEXTCOLOR(11);

        WRITE('D ':25);
        TEXTCOLOR(15);
        WRITELN(': Display All Orders');
        WRITELN;
        TEXTCOLOR(11);

        WRITE('X ':25);
        TEXTCOLOR(15);
        WRITELN(': Quit');
        WRITELN;

        WRITE('Enter choice: ':23);
        orderMenuChoice:=UPCASE(READKEY);
        sndPlaySound('F:\School\IB 1\HL subjects\Computer Science\Pascal programs\InternalAssessment\sound files\beep.wav', snd_Async or snd_NoDefault );
        TEXTCOLOR(11);
        WRITELN(orderMenuChoice);
        DELAY(200);
        TEXTCOLOR(15);


        CASE orderMenuChoice OF

           'A' : CreateCustomerOrder;
           'B' : searchForCustomerOrder;
           'C' : DeleteCustomerOrder;
           'D' : DisplayAllOrders;
           'X' : WRITELN('Goodbye.');

        ELSE
        BEGIN
           WRITELN;
           TEXTCOLOR(12);
           WRITELN('ERROR - Only Enter A-D Or X To Exit. Try Again.');
           TEXTCOLOR(15);
           READLN;
        END
        END;

     UNTIL OrderMenuChoice = 'X';

  END;
```

I've never used graphics in programming before so i have no idea where to start.
What library do I need?

I already have USES CRT, SYSUTILS, USES32,  etc...
Which is the correct one for using graphics?

Comment: See if it has an unit "GRAPH". That is the normal TP way. VP has been dead for over a decade though, so better change to Free Pascal.

Comment: First: Yes, switch to Free Pascal. 
Second: Since you are already using some graphics by using Crt's text color, you could use the mouse to make your menu items clickable:
[How to run procedure on mouse click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995444/how-to-run-a-procedure-after-user-clicks-on-it-with-mouse-pascal/26006314#26006314). That might also work on Virtual Pascal.

And if you decide to switch to Free Pascal. Take a look at [Lazarus project](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/). With this you can make GUI applications in Pascal!